# Accessing DOM element using document.name and document.id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I am new to javascript, and I know how to access DOM elements using `getElementByXxx()` methods. But in one example I saw that it's possible to access elements directly using their name or like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form name="myForm"><input type="button" id="btn"></form>
    <script>
    console.log(document.myForm);
    console.log(document.myForm.btn);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="button" id="btn">
</form>
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

Which is very confusing to me. Google and online courses only say about `getElementById()`, `querySelector()`, and objects (and object collections). I really don't understand how this works. When I change to id for form it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="myForm"><input type="button" id="btn"></form>
    <script>
    console.log(document.myForm);
    console.log(document.myForm.btn);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console:

```
undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'btn' of undefined
```

Also it seems like it only work with form and input, and not for paragraph or div. Am I missing some obvious things here? I'm sorry if my question is too basic.

Comment: Don't rely on automatic references to DOM elements, they can easily be overridden with global variables. Always use a proper query method to fetch a reference.

Comment: I definitely prefer `getElementById()` and `querySelector()`, but you said one example shows "that it's possible to access elements directly using their **name** like...". However, you have only given the elements an **id**, not a name.

Comment: More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: @user1599011 Sorry I should be clear that both name and id are in the example. Edited.

Comment: @James Thank you so much. It makes so much sense for me now.